# Add calculated Field between Pivot 'Columns' based on 'Values' data

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a report that I am working on to show variance between two quarterly periods. I have an SQL query that I am reading into a pandas dataframe, and then pivoting.

Here is my code for that piece:

```
    df = pd.read_sql_query(mtd_query, cnxn, params=[report_start, end_mtd, report_start, end_mtd, whse])
    ##(m-1)//3 + 1  Determine which Quarter each month is
    ## Create the "Period" column by combining the Quater and the Month
    df['QUARTER'] = (df['INV_MONTH'].astype(int) - 1)//3 + 1
    df['PERIOD'] = df['INV_YEAR'].astype(str) + 'Q' + df['QUARTER'].astype(int).astype(str)
    df['MARGIN'] = (df['PROFIT'].astype(float) / df['SALES'].astype(float))

    df = df.drop('INV_MONTH', axis=1)
    df = df.drop('INV_YEAR', axis=1)
    df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['REP', 'REP_NAME', 'CUST_NO', 'CUST_NAME', 'TOTALSALES'], columns=['PERIOD'], values=['SALES', 'PROFIT', 'MARGIN'], fill_value=0)
    df = df.reorder_levels([1, 0], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
    df = df.sortlevel(level=0, ascending=True)
```

I am trying to determine the difference between the 'MARGIN' columns between 'PERIOD'.  I have been unable to find any way to accomplish this.  Any suggestion is appreciated.

Current Output shows:

```
PERIOD                                                                                            2017Q4                                 2017Q3                                 2017Q2                                 2017Q1                                 2016Q4                        
                                                                                                   SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN          SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN          SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN          SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN          SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN
REP    REP_NAME                       CUST_NO  CUST_NAME                      TOTALSALES                                                                                                                                                                                                    
1.0    Greensboro - House             245.0    TE CONNECTIVITY CORPORATION    103361.05         0.000000      0.000000  0.000000     434.500000     69.520000  0.160000   20391.666667   3262.666667  0.160000       0.000000      0.000000  0.000000       0.000000      0.000000  0.000000
                                      1789.0   GOOD HOUSEKEEPER               50108.47        678.508182     80.170909  0.145883     585.301429     64.180476  0.121915     718.685000     92.033125  0.130453     720.729333     97.955333  0.134821    1237.308333     88.210000  0.099450
```

Desired Output would look like below:

```
PERIOD                                                                                            2017Q4                                 2017Q3                                 2017Q2                                 2017Q1                                 2016Q4                        
                                                                                                   SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN   VARIANCE          SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN    VARIANCE          SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN    VARIANCE          SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN    VARIANCE          SALES        PROFIT    MARGIN
REP    REP_NAME                       CUST_NO  CUST_NAME                      TOTALSALES                                                                                                                                                                                                    
1.0    Greensboro - House             245.0    TE CONNECTIVITY CORPORATION    103361.05         0.000000      0.000000  0.000000    -.16         434.500000     69.520000  0.160000    0           20391.666667   3262.666667  0.160000    .16           0.000000      0.000000  0.000000      0            0.000000      0.000000  0.000000
                                      1789.0   GOOD HOUSEKEEPER               50108.47        678.508182     80.170909  0.145883    .023968     585.301429     64.180476  0.121915    -0.008537     718.685000     92.033125  0.130453    -.004368     720.729333     97.955333  0.134821     .035372       1237.308333     88.210000  0.099450
```

df.to_dict('r') below:

```
[{('2016Q4', 'SALES'): 0.0, ('2017Q3', 'PROFIT'): 69.520000000000067, ('2017Q1', 'PROFIT'): 0.0, ('2017Q2', 'SALES'): 20391.666666666668, ('2017Q3', 'MARGIN'): 0.16, ('2016Q4', 'PROFIT'): 0.0, ('2017Q3', 'SALES'): 434.5, ('2017Q1', 'SALES'): 0.0, ('2017Q4', 'SALES'): 0.0, ('2016Q4', 'MARGIN'): 0.0, ('2017Q4', 'PROFIT'): 0.0, ('2017Q1', 'MARGIN'): 0.0, ('2017Q4', 'MARGIN'): 0.0, ('2017Q2', 'MARGIN'): 0.16, ('2017Q2', 'PROFIT'): 3262.6666666666665}, {('2016Q4', 'SALES'): 1237.3083333333332, ('2017Q3', 'PROFIT'): 64.180476190476185, ('2017Q1', 'PROFIT'): 97.9553333333333, ('2017Q2', 'SALES'): 718.68500000000006, ('2017Q3', 'MARGIN'): 0.1219152103415191, ('2016Q4', 'PROFIT'): 88.209999999999994}]
```

Comment: @MaxU Done...  I apologize for the desired, had to manually fudge it :)

Comment: Could you please post an output of `print(df.to_dict('r'))` for your source (pivoted) DF, as it will take us quite some time to reproduce this multi-index, multi-column DF...

Comment: @MaxU done.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the above solution to work.
So I did this:

```
df['MARGIN'] = (df['PROFIT'].astype(float) / df['SALES'].astype(float))
df['MARGIN'] = df['MARGIN'].astype(float)
df['PREV_MARGIN'] = df['MARGIN'].shift(-1)
df['VARIANCE'] = df['MARGIN'] - df['PREV_MARGIN']
df = df.drop('PREV_MARGIN', axis=1)
```

This gets me the data I need to complete my work.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

Source DF:

```
In [60]: df
Out[60]:
  2016Q4                     2017Q1                  2017Q2               \
  MARGIN PROFIT        SALES MARGIN     PROFIT SALES MARGIN       PROFIT
0    0.0   0.00     0.000000    0.0   0.000000   0.0   0.16  3262.666667
1    NaN  88.21  1237.308333    NaN  97.955333   NaN    NaN          NaN

                   2017Q3                   2017Q4
          SALES    MARGIN     PROFIT  SALES MARGIN PROFIT SALES
0  20391.666667  0.160000  69.520000  434.5    0.0    0.0   0.0
1    718.685000  0.121915  64.180476    NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
```

Solution:

```
In [61]: tmp = (df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'MARGIN']]
    ...:          .fillna(0)
    ...:          .diff(axis=1)
    ...:          .rename(columns=lambda x: 'VARIANCE' if x=='MARGIN' else x))
    ...:

In [62]: pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
Out[62]:
  2016Q4                              2017Q1                           2017Q2  \
  MARGIN PROFIT        SALES VARIANCE MARGIN     PROFIT SALES VARIANCE MARGIN
0    0.0   0.00     0.000000      NaN    0.0   0.000000   0.0      0.0   0.16
1    NaN  88.21  1237.308333      NaN    NaN  97.955333   NaN      0.0    NaN

                                         2017Q3                              \
        PROFIT         SALES VARIANCE    MARGIN     PROFIT  SALES  VARIANCE
0  3262.666667  20391.666667     0.16  0.160000  69.520000  434.5  0.000000
1          NaN    718.685000     0.00  0.121915  64.180476    NaN  0.121915

  2017Q4
  MARGIN PROFIT SALES  VARIANCE
0    0.0    0.0   0.0 -0.160000
1    NaN    NaN   NaN -0.121915
```

Comment: it didn't like the df.loc, so I tried df.iloc and now I'm getting errors at the Slice:    `TypeError: unorderable types: slice() >= str()`  I'm not sure how to get around that.  Tried doing an `.asype(float)` on the margin column, but no go.